# Why does the compiler treat those two equivalent(?) lines differently?

Tags: rust

From what I understand, when `x` implements trait `Foo`,
the following two lines should be equivalent.

```
x.foo();
Foo::foo(&x);
```

However, I am facing a problem where the compiler accepts the first one, and rejects the second one, with a rather strange error message.

As usual, this example is [available on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4b8ada5cc29c06387581d29d45701caf).

Consider the following two related traits.

```
pub trait Bar<'a> {
    type BarError: Into<MyError>;
    fn bar(&self) -> Result<(), Self::BarError>;
}

pub trait Foo: for<'a> Bar<'a> {
    type FooError: Into<MyError>;
    fn foo(&self) -> Result<(), Self::FooError>
    where
        for<'a> <Self as Bar<'a>>::BarError: Into<<Self as Foo>::FooError>;
}
```

This example is a bit complex, but I do need the lifetime parameter on `Bar`, and I can't have it on `Foo`. As a consequence:

- I have to resort on [Higher-Rank Trait Bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) (HRTB);
- I can not rely on `Bar::BarError` in `Foo` (there are actually an infinite number of types `Bar<'_>::BarError`), so `Foo` must have its own `FooError`;
- and so I need the complex trait bound in the `foo` method to convert `BarError`s to `FooError`s.

Now, let's implement `Bar` and `Foo` for a concrete type, e.g. `Vec<i32>`.

```
impl<'a> Bar<'a> for Vec<i32> {
    type BarError = Never;
    fn bar(&self) /* ... */
}

impl Foo for Vec<i32> {
    type FooError = Never;
    fn foo(&self) /* ... */
}
```

Note that `Never` is an empty enum, indicating that these implementations never fail. In order to comply with the trait definitions, `From<Never>` is implemented for `MyError`.

We can now demonstrate the problem: the following compiles like charm.

```
let x = vec![1, 2, 3];
let _ = x.foo();
```

But the following des not.

```
let x = vec![1, 2, 3];
let _ = Foo::foo(&x);
```

The error messages says:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<std::vec::Vec<i32> as Foo>::FooError == MyError`
  --> src/main.rs:49:13
   |
49 |     let _ = Foo::foo(&x);
   |             ^^^^^^^^ expected enum `Never`, found struct `MyError`
   |
   = note: expected type `Never`
              found type `MyError`
```

The compiler seems to believe that I wrote something like this (NB: this is not correct Rust, but just to give the idea).

```
let _ = Foo::<FooError=MyError>::foo(&x);
```

And this does not work because `x` implements `Foo<FooError=Never>`.

Why does the compiler adds this additional constraint? Is it a bug? If not, is it possible to write it otherwise so it compiles?

NB: you may wonder why I don't just stick to the first version (`x.foo(&x)`). In my actual situation, `foo` is actually named `retain`, which is also the name of a method in `Vec`. So I must use the second form, to avoid the ambiguity.

NB2: if I remove the HRTB in the declaration of method `foo`, both lines compile. But then I can not call `Bar::bar` in any implementation of `Foo::foo`, which is not an option for me. And changing `foo` to something like `fn foo<'a>(&'a self) -> Result<(), <Self as Bar<'a>>::BarError)` is not an option either, unfortunately.

Comment: This seems to be a known [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/56556). And check this out: "The only workaround I know of is to remove the lifetime parameter". Ouch.

Comment: @edwardw thanks for the pointer. I'm not sure yet this is the exact same problem, though. The error message is not the same anyway. But they may have the same root cause...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> From what I understand, when x implements trait Foo, the following two lines should be equivalent.
>
> ```
> x.foo();
> Foo::foo(&x);
> ```

This is true for an inherent method (one that is defined on the type of `x` itself), but not for a trait method. In your case the equivalent is `<Vec<i32> as Foo>::foo(&x);`.

Here is [a playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d42c580007143f7a78ed795088077663)

Comment: While it has nothing to do with the specific problem at hand, it's also worth pointing out that the dot-method-call-syntax does some things like auto-referencing and dereferencing. So the two lines are generally not equivalent, even in cases less crazy than this one.

Comment: Oh, this makes sense! Thanks a lot, fellow lyonnais rustacean ;-)

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt yes, indeed, x.foo() could be Foo:foo(&mut x) or Foo:foo(x) depending on how foo is declared...